# j_security_check login.jsp is not working with WebSphere Liberty profile

Tags: spring, jsp, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have my LDAP configuration in server.xml in Websphere Liberty profile as follows.

```
 <ldapRegistry   baseDN="dc=mydc,dc=myroot,dc=myorg" bindDN="cn=myname,OU=Users,OU=myou,DC=mydc,DC=myroot,DC=myorg" bindPassword="xxxx" host="mycompanyldap" id="ldap" ignoreCase="true" ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" port="389" realm="LdapRegistry" sslEnabled="false">
<activedFilters groupMemberIdMap="memberof:member" />
<activedFilters groupMemberIdMap="memberOf:member" />
    </ldapRegistry>
```

I have my login.jsp which has this call in it..

```
<form name="frmLogin" action="j_security_check" method="POST">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table id="loginPanel">
                <thead>
                    <th id="titleRow" colspan="2">Media Inquiries</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="firstRow">
                        <td class="label">LAN ID:</td>
                        <td class="field"><input type="text" id="j_username"  name="j_username" maxlength="20" style="width: 150;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"> Password: </td>
                        <td class="field"><input type="password" id="j_password"  name="j_password" maxlength="20" style="width: 150;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="submitRow" colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Logon" onclick="return submitPage()">                    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following defined in my web.xml

```
    <!-- ========== Begin Authentication ========== -->
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>All Users Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>All Users Authorization Constraint</description>
        <role-name>All Users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>LdapRegistry</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp?loginFailed=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>All Users</role-name>
</security-role>
<!-- ========== End Authentication ========== -->

<!-- Declare Spring Security filter -->
<!-- Add a DelegatingFilterProxy -->
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Add a springSecurityFilterChain mapping -->
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I do the login using the form login , nothing happens on the front end.
I check the logs and there is this message.

```
[2/9/16 11:42:27:593 CST] 00000054 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.ws.security.registry.RegistryException: CWIML0515E: The user registry operation could not be completed. The CN=myname,OU=Users,OU=myou,DC=mydc,DC=myroot,DC=myorg entity is not in the scope of the defined realm. Specify an entity that is in the scope of the configured realm in the server.xml file. com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule 93" at ffdc_16.02.09_11.42.27.0.log
```

WebSphere documentation shows this.. which is the exact message I received but I am not clear as to what I need to do to fix my server.xml.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.wim.util.resources.WimUtilMessages.html

```
CWIML0515E: The user registry operation could not be completed. The {0} entity is not in the scope of the {1} realm. Specify an entity that is in the scope of the configured realm in the server.xml file.
**Explanation** The operation cannot be performed because the specified entity is not in the scope of the realm.

**Action**  Ensure that the unique name of the entity is specified correctly. If a realm name is specified in the Context object of the input object, ensure that the name is spelt correctly.
```

Can someone please help as to what I need to do to have my LDAP work correctly with my login. What do I need to change in my server.xml ?

Thanks
Dhiren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
This needs to be added to either the web application or ear.
Note the realm of the ldap should be the LdapRealm that you set.

```
  <application-bnd>
<security-role name="All Users">
                 <special-subject id="group:LdapRegistry/cn=yourCN,OU=Users,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=" type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/> 

                 <special-subject id="user:LdapRegistry/cn=yourCN,OU=Users,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=" type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/>
</security-role>

</application-bnd>
```

Once you set this up. the war and ear can communicate with LDAP